# Why does my session only start with this unique session variable?

Tags: php, session

If $u and $d match the session will register.  However if I change the string of $d to anything else, the session will not register even though everything else passes.  I was wanting to register the session under the users full name as stored in the table users.  Is there something I am not seeing?

```
<?php
        include('conn.php');
        $u = $_POST['user'];
        $p = md5($_POST['pass']);
        $sql = "SELECT first_name, last_name, user, pass FROM users WHERE user = :user AND pass = :pass";
            $q = $conn->prepare($sql);
            $q->bindParam(":user", $u);
            $q->bindParam(":pass", $p);
            $q->execute();
            $login = $q->fetch();
            $d = $login['user'];
            if($login['user']){
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['login_user']=$d;
                header('Location: index.php');

            }
            else{
                header('Location: login.php');
            }
?>
```

EDIT:  I've edited to show a better example of what I mean.  If I was to change the variable $d to $login['first_name'], then the session will not register.  Even though that information is correct in the database because it displays the first name on index.php when it is successful.

Comment: Can you include a case where _the session will not register_? Also with the output of `var_dump(get_defined_vars());`. Beware not to expose sensitive information in the output though.

Comment: It seems to be checking the database for a verified username and password. Which bit is unclear? The SQL is pretty straightforward - it uses two params - username and password which are bound using `$u` and `$p`. If the user is verified, it stores the session using `$_SESSION['login_user']=$d;` which is defined above it as `$d = "user01";` Change that.

Comment: A side note: is it correct that you are using md5 hashes for password protection? That is highly insecure!

Comment: An obvious one: Have you looked at the data in the database? I always ask my customers: "Have you plugged it in?", and a fair percentage hasn't.

Comment: For instance if the username is "user01" and the password is "123abc", then the supplied code will function.  However if I changed the variable $d to say "user02" then it will fail.

Comment: arkascha - could you direct me to a more secure password protection method?  This site has no personal information and is more less for admin users.  But if there is a more secure practice I am unaware of, I would love to start using it.

Comment: @DustinSpicer maybe I am not clear enough. I mean how do you check whether the session is registered or not?

Comment: @DustinSpicer Regarding password hashing, see this reference: https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm Using `md5()` is not the most serious flaw; **without salting is**.

Comment: @cychoi I am just checking based on if it redirects to index.php.

Comment: @cychoi also thanks for the password hashing article.  I will be reading over this for sure.

Comment: @DustinSpicer From your comment, "session is not registered" actually means `$login['user']` is `FALSE`. Can you double check the query actually returns something for that particular username and password pair? Such as doing the query in PHPMyAdmin or `var_dump()`ing the `$login` variable, etc.

Comment: @cychoi maybe my wording was off, but yes the username and password pair.  I have run it inside of PHPMyAdmin.  Trying to register the session to $login['first_name'] fails and redirects to the login.php.  I'm just trying to understand why I can only register the session to login['user'].

Comment: @DustinSpicer it's not helping if you refuse to look inside the contents of the variables. Not much I can help debugging the problem. At least, you should do a `var_dump()` inside the `else{}` block and see why you are getting there.

Comment: @cychoi my apologies.  I did the var_dump and it actually is registering the variable to $login['first_name'].  However it just redirects to the login page.  The reason for that is from another file where I am checking the session on the index.php to the user in the table.  I feel like an idiot for overlooking that.

Comment: @DustinSpicer Cool that you found the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the code, `$d` is defined using the following:

```
$d = "user01";
```

and later it is used again (once the username and password are verified) to:

```
$_SESSION['login_user']=$d;
```

If you want to change the session being saved as the users full name, change the `execcute` statement to a `query` statement and return the row from the database. Then store the save whatever the column is that has the user's name to the session.

Assuming you change the execute to a query - you could use something like:

```
$_SESSION['login_user']=$result['username'];
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by changing the execute to a query?